# Tensorflow error using my own data for text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, text-classification

I've been playing with the Tensorflow library doing the tutorials.

I'm using this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification_save_restore.py#L1). And I changed the parameters in the example from this: `n_classes = 15` 
to this: `n_classes = 2` as I have only two classes to classify.

I read data like:

```
train = pandas.read_csv('tensorflow_feed/test/train_with_abs.csv', header=None)
X_train, y_train = train[1], train[0]
test = pandas.read_csv('tensorflow_feed/test/test_with_abs.csv', header=None)
X_test, y_test = test[1], test[0]
```

But it gives following error:

```
Total words: 35
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sumit/PycharmProjects/experiments/text_classification_save_restore.py", line 94, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/base.py", line 160, in fit
    monitors=monitors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 449, in _train_model
    train_op, loss_op = self._get_train_ops(features, targets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 673, in _get_train_ops
    _, loss, train_op = self._call_model_fn(features, targets, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 656, in _call_model_fn
    features, targets, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/base.py", line 369, in _model_fn
    predictions, loss = model_fn(features, targets)
  File "/home/sumit/PycharmProjects/experiments/text_classification_save_restore.py", line 73, in rnn_model
    word_list = tf.unpack(word_vectors, axis=1)
TypeError: unpack() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "axis" parameter was just added to tf.unpack on June 23, and the example you're looking at was changed to use it:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/eff93149a6dc8e6826898fd9f9c28c81e21c9836

So I suggest either:

- use an older version of the example from before that commit, e.g.:
  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/892ca4ddc12852a7b4633fd08f163941356cb4e6/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification_save_restore.py
- build a newer Tensorflow from github HEAD.

I hope that helps!